# WooCommerce - How can I make single product gallery show two images on the slider at once?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to display two images in the single page product gallery slider at once like the photo below. I use woocommerce and I can't seem to find any plugin that supports this. Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Elementor and JetEngine.
In WooBuilder use JetProductGallery and set the options like this
[image: In WooBuilder use JetProductGallery and set the options like this]